# set display name while creating user with firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a react app with which I want to handle authentication with firebase.

My code successfully signs up and logs in but i am trying to add extra information on sign up but i have not been successful. I have tried answers [here]: [Firebase v3 updateProfile Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559457/firebase-v3-updateprofile-method) and [here]: [Firebase user.updateProfile({...}) not working in React App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487388/firebase-user-updateprofile-not-working-in-react-app/47521392)

But they don't seem to work. Below is my code

```
const SignUp = ({ history }) => {
  const handleSignUp = useCallback(
    async event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const { email, password } = event.target.elements;
      try {
        let cred = await app
          .auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);
        await cred.user.updateProfile({
          displayName: 'hello'
        });

        history.push('/');
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
    [history]
  );
```

Please how do i fix this because currently on the email and username sets? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change user profile you should use firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged() function, as follows:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Then you can get others user properties. Here you can find all info you need. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users. Hope it helps.