# DisplayName not being set when using Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get Firebase to assign users a name based off of what they put into a field. However it appears that the name isnt being updated doesnt do anything.

```
btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', e => {
    //Get Email and Password
    const acEmail = email.value;
    const acPass = password.value;
    const acName = name.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();

    //Sign Up
    const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(acEmail, acPass);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
    then(function(user) {
          user.updateProfile({
            displayName: acName
          })
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
});
```

Any help is Appreciated!

Comment: What does the method updateProfile do? Please link docs for that method.

Comment: Did you already see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559457/firebase-v3-updateprofile-method